# How to resolve in Visual Studio 2013: Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'this package that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, google-api, nuget, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting this in Visual Studio trying to reference the **Google API Library.** Here is what I see:

I have looked around and made sure everything is up to date.

Visual Studio 2013 is Update 2 and my NuGet package is up to date. I am able to compile and run using my phone which is running Windows phone 8.1.

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Google.Apis.Core (≥ 1.8.2)'.<br />
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.5)'.<br />
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.0.19)'.<br />
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.10)'.<br />
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async (≥ 1.0.16)'.<br />
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.1.10)'.<br />
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Zlib.Portable (≥ 1.9.2)'.<br />
Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'.<br />
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'.<br />
Installing 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'.<br />
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'.<br />
Installing 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.7'.<br />
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.7'.<br />
Installing 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.16'.<br />
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.16'.<br />
Installing 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.1.10'.<br />
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.1.10'.<br />
Installing 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'.
.<br />
Successfully installed 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'. <br />
Installing 'Google.Apis.Core 1.8.2'.<br />
Successfully installed 'Google.Apis.Core 1.8.2'.<br />
Installing 'Google.Apis 1.8.2'.<br />
Successfully installed 'Google.Apis 1.8.2'.<br />
Adding 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5' to XXXX.<br />
Uninstalling 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'.<br />
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'.<br />
```

Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package **'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5'**. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: Why is NuGet trying to install Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.5 when the newest version is 6.0.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install latest Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3 this package version supports wpa81.

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then install Google.Apis.Core and it will use already newest version installed of Newtonsoft.Json package.

```
Install-Package Google.Apis.Core
```

Comment: I was able to get past the newtonsoft.json error, but when trying to install the google.apis.core I get same errors for the following 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.16', 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.1.10' and search for both of them and updated them, but then I get to Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'., and when I try that by itself, I get the error: Could not install package 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', While I still have an issue Gheorghe you did answer the question, so thank you.